# ¿Cómo hacer la lectura de este JSON?

Tags: php, laravel, json

Estoy obteniendo los datos de una API, la URL es la siguiente `https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/test/Property?access_token=6baca547742c6f96a6ff71b138424f21`

Estoy tratando de obtenerla de la siguiente manera:

En mi controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = file_get_contents("https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/test/Property?access_token=6baca547742c6f96a6ff71b138424f21");
    
    $properties = json_decode($data, true);

    return view('welcome', compact('properties'));
}
```

Sí hago un `dd($properties)` dentro del controlador, me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en la vista si elimino el `dd($properties)` del controlador para leer los datos del JSON:

```
@foreach ($properties as $key => $property)
        
    {{ $property['value'][$key]->ListPrice }}

@endforeach
```

Me da el siguiente error `TypeError Cannot access offset of type string on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\api\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)`

Comment: concretamente que quieres obtener del json ? solo los listPrice?

Comment: No solo los `listPrice` pero al obtenerlo ya podría acceder al resto

Comment: es que no puedes imprimir todas los valores de los objetos porque mirando el endpoint cada item en algunas llaves tiene una matriz, si solo quieres recuperar el list price te puedo ayudar

Comment: Ayúdame con listPrice a ver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para acceder al listPrice desde blade puedes hacerlo mediante el loop del atributo value asi

```
 @foreach ($properties['value'] as $key=>$value)
    {{$value['ListPrice']}}
@endforeach
```

teniendo en cuenta que es un array multidimensional deberías hacer un for anidado pero para solo el precio funciona

Comment: Muchas Gracias, para todos los elementos que están en la misma línea que `listPrice` funciona, sí, ahora debo buscar de leer los que están en el otro nivel, por ejemplo `FireplaceFeatures` que tiene varios elementos dentro de él.

Comment: Debe anidar un for o ir directamente al indice, guiate por el primer loop

Comment: Ya hice algo, pero creo que será mejor iniciar otra pregunta, la voy a publicar.

Comment: Logre hacerlo, pero no sé si sea la manera correcta de resolverlo... La publicaré

Comment: Cuando puedas revisa la otra pregunta y me das tu opinión `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450068/est%c3%a1-ser%c3%ada-la-manera-correcta-de-acceder-a-los-elementos-de-un-array-multidimen?noredirect=1#comment801928_450068` gracias!